# excel: how to determine if date is within a range of dates

Tags: excel

I have following data in my Excel worksheet:

```
A1: dec. 25, 2017
A2: feb. 25, 2018
A3: jan. 27, 2018
A4: 1
A5: 2
A6: (this is where result should be)
```

My current formula for `A6` is:

```
if(and(datevalue(text(A2,"mm/dd/yy")) >= datevalue(text(A1,"mm/dd/yy")), datevalue(text(A2,"mm/dd/yy")) <= datevalue(text(A3,"mm/dd/yy"))), A4/A5, 0)
```

And it genereates `0` with the data provided above which is wrong.

The equation works in dates with the same year but it doesn't work with different year like the example above. I'm working on my scheduling work and I really appreciate if you can help me. thanks

Comment: are the dates exactly in the same format as in this question

Answer (score 1):

If `A1:A3` are properly formatted to date(time) value, it should not be so difficult to manipulate them. `=if(and(a2>=a1, a2<=a3), ...)` is enough.

If not, first format them properly. For example, if `A1` is string '`dec. 25, 2017`', next formula will convert `A1` to a valid date value.

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4), MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)), MID(A1,6,2))
```

Getting a month number from a month string is from [this article](https://a4accounting.com.au/excel-convert-text-month-to-the-month-number/).